How to use hunspell dictionaries in Thunderbird snap?
Is it possible to use my installed hunspell dictionaries in Thunderbird if Thunderbird is installed via snap?
For Firefox, this is working even with the snap version.
I can install dictionaries as Addons, but I would like to have a central place for my dictionaries.
Thunderbird 128.3.1esr (64-bit)
Ubuntu 24.04
